# ListBox item template depends on item values

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

In WPF, MVVC applicaiton I have quite normal listbox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}">
</ListBox>
```

Then each item of list uses following datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Friend}">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="3" Name="border" Margin="3">
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="DescriptionDTDataType" Text="{Binding Path=ConnectedUserID}" />
            <TextBlock Name="StatusTitle" Margin="8,0,4,0">Status:</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="Status" Text="{Binding Path=Approved}" />
            <Button Content="Approve" Command="{x:Static inf:Commands.ApproveUserConnection}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
            <Button Content="Disapprove" Command="{x:Static inf:Commands.DisapproveUserConnection}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

The question is... I want to hide one of the buttons on the basic of Friend.Approved property. For example if Friend.Approved has value "approved" I want to hide button Approved and show only button Dissaprove. On the other hand if Friend.Approved has value "disapproved" then I want opposite. How to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside creating a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) there is a pure XAML solution using [DataTriggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx)

Just add this to your DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Approved}" Value="approved" >
        <Setter TargetName="Approve" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Approved}" Value="disapproved" >
        <Setter TargetName="Disapprove" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

And name your buttons:

```
<Button Name="Approve" Content="Approve" ...></Button>
<Button Name="Disapprove" Content="Disapprove" ...></Button>
```

However if you want to reuse this hiding logic in multiple places in multiple DataTemplates its better to write the Approved text to Visibility converter.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Buttons Visibility property to `Approved` and use a value converter to convert `Approved` to a Visibility value.